# overhead in loading model if only using one function codeigniter/php

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, model, load

Suppose a have a controller (let's call it "main") and an associated model which performs a bunch (10) of functions.

i'm wondering about the associated overhead in loading a 2nd model to do one function that doesn't exist in the main model vs. just adding that function (duplicating the code) in the main model.

The pros in loading that 2nd model are less code/easier to maintain.

The cons are overhead of loading a 2nd model.

Are my fears of overhead valid? I'm a non CS person and just wondering what's the best practice here.

thanks,
tim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).  If you do you will only make your life a lot harder than it should have been when it comes to maintaining your code down the line.  The principles of good OOP encourage you to create classes with a specific area of responsibility, and using that class to handle the situations it was built for.  Duplicating functionality in class X into class Y violates this principle.  If class Y needs to do something class X does, then this means that either class Y needs to talk to an instance of class X, or class Y should inherit from class X.

It would also be a [micro-optimization](/questions/tagged/micro-optimization) at best.  The performance hit for loading the other class should be negligible, certainly nothing worth worrying about.

Comment: hi GordonM, thanks for the advice. I have no sense of the performance hit but that is what i'm wondering about. If you say it is negligible that is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you instanciate your object.
For PHP classes, you can define what to load when you create an object (see constructor).
Most of the time, yes, it's better to have a clean and clear code for maintenance but sometimes, for business reasons, it's better to duplicate some code, even it's difficult to maintain. I read here only the point of view from developers (I am one...) but according my opinion, a good developer should always think about the functionalities/business first, even that means he needs to produce more code for better User Experience or sometimes he needs to code something dirty/quick/difficult to maintain but it works for users!

Comment: hi Yoong, I don't have to load it in the constructor though that would be the laziest/easiest approach. So you are advocating in general to duplicate the code?

Comment: no, I just wrote that it depends on your needs...When you include another model and call the method, that's good for maintenance and reusability. But if you modify your method too many times because your needs evolve, then you should rethink about that...your question is difficult to reply for us because we don't know all the details...

Comment: ok thanks, i think I go with simplest approach which is to reuse the code. I can always refactor later if my needs change. thanks!